# Having difficulty with this code. Does not want to run

Tags: r, ggplot2

I keep getting an error message. The message involves the facet wrap. I made severl attempts to try to adjust the code but it did not work

```
?gapminder
View(gapminder)

filter(country %in% c("Argentina", "Algeria")) %>% 
filter(pop < 20000000) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x= gdpPercap,
         y = lifeExp,
         size = pop,
         color = year))+
geom_point()+
facet_wrap(~ country)+
labs = (title = "Life Expectancy explained by GDP per capita",
      x = "GDP per capita",
      y = "Life Expectancy")
```

Tried to leave out the facet wrap but that did not work

Comment: Remove the equal sign from near labs. 

It is `labs (title = "Life Expectancy explained by GDP per capita",
      x = "GDP per capita",
      y = "Life Expectancy")`

**labs** is a function

Comment: The title of your post should help people with a similar problem in the future find the same answer. Generic requests for help aren't ultimately helpful. You should also give the specific error message you encounter so we can verify we can re-create the problem to diagnosis it. Just saying something "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive. Is it actually returning an error or are you just getting something other than what you expected, and if so, what exactly did you expect as output?

Comment: Your `%>%`-pipe does not start from data, shouldn't you use `gapminder %>% filter(country %in% ...) %>% ...`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion . but it still did not work

Comment: I expected to get a a plot as the output to my code

Answer (score 0):

Your code have '=' sign near labs function that lead to error. Try the below code and it should fix it

```
   gapminder%>%
    filter(country %in% c("Argentina", "Algeria")) %>% 
    filter(pop < 20000000) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x= gdpPercap,
             y = lifeExp,
             size = pop,
             color = year))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~ country)+
    labs (title = "Life Expectancy explained by GDP per capita",
          x = "GDP per capita",
          y = "Life Expectancy")
```